# How to parse a entirely html table from button and textview the sqlite table

Tags: java, android, html, sqlite, jsoup

The idea is to parse the [link](http://www.usp.br/coseas/COSEASHP/COSEAS2010_cardapio.html) on click and transform it to a sqlite table, overwriting it always that the button is clicked again. My code before was only printing out everything, not separating data to cells, and I can't figure out how to adjust it.
Tried to understand the code in [Java (Android) Html Table Parsing to Database (SQLite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325067/java-android-html-table-parsing-to-database-sqlite), but still not very clear to me.

```
public class BandecoActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bandeco);
    Button updatebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonupdate);

    updatebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String url = "http://www.usp.br/coseas/cardapio.html";
                    TextView cardapiotextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textcardapio);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bandeco);
                    try {
                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                        Elements rows = doc.select("tr pre");

                        for (Element elem: rows) {
                           System.out.println(elem.text());
                           cardapiotextview.append(elem.text());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }       
                }
                }.start();



        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bandeco, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Instead of printing out, I need to add to a sqlite table. After all the jsoup running, is necessary to textview the table in the activity. Please help as I'm new in android programming.

Comment: You have to create a new class for DBHandler that class should expand with `SQLiteOpenHelper`. For the reference http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ it will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try and follow these steps:

1. Open browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, ... and never IE)
2. Go to address bar and type `www.google.com` and press `Enter Key`
3. In search type `How to set text to textview android`
4. Click on one of the results and go thru it
5. If not enough info, then go to another result
6. Go to step 5 until you find answer
7. Go to step 2 for `How to CRUD sqlite android`
8. Enlightenment